# PDFkit with wkhtmltopdf recognizes line breaks on mac but not on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf

I have seen similar questions, but nothing exactly like this - i beleive it to be a config issue, but i don't know where in the chain.

I am able to successfully generate pdfs using pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf on both my mac and my ubuntu env - ubuntu being production.

There are slight rendering issues with the ubuntu version that are not there on the mac.

The biggest/most important issue being the page breaks which I achieve with this css:

```
div.page{
    page-break-after: always !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

This is my python code (flask) for generating the pdf:

```
@app.route('/report/<report_key>.pdf')
def report_pdf(report_key):
    #replace with sso
    user_id = 1
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
    try:
        report = _generate_report(report_key)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("could not get report for {}: {}".format(report_key, e))
        raise HTTPException
    else:
        template = render_template('report-pdf.html', report=report)

        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(template.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'), False, configuration=config)

        response = make_response(pdf)
        response.mimetype = 'application/pdf'
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={}_{}.pdf".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime()), report_key)
        return response
```

I can only assume it is a user agent issue - however - that doesn't make sense as webkit should recognize the breaks (and I am all but sure the WK in wkhtmltopdf means webkit).

On the ubuntu server I am using xvfb to connect pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf - using this command I see everywhere:

```
echo 'xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf $*' > /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2020

I have tried this but it fails, I can't seem to find the proper way to send the custom-header (and propagation) options via pdfkit. That said I don't know if that is even the solution.

Any help would be great, Thansk

(BTW, this is a new acct for me. i quit FB and had to start a new one on SO - my old username had a rep of 1k - bummer.)

Comment: + 1 I have exactly the same problem. My local setup works perfectly on mac osx wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2, all divs with "page-break-inside: avoid" are dutifully preserved intact. With exactly the same version of wkhtmltopdf running on Ubuntu 12.04 and exactly the same html templates, same content... they get cut. I have no idea what is going on and it is *really* irritating

Comment: cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243452/why-xvfb-is-breaking-wkhtmltopdf-output

Comment: it may be related to xvfb as that is the only difference between the two environments